# Filter with regex MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, filter

I am trying to match the fields of `originalEmail` with a mail address like liron@gmail.com, but no matter, case sensitive means to also find LirOn@gmail.com fields.

```
public ObjectId? GetEntityIdByOriginalEmail(string originalEmail)
{
    FilterDefinition<Entity> filter = "{ x : { $regex : /" + originalEmail + "//i } }";
    var entity = _entitiesStorage.GetSingleOrDefault(filter);

    if (entity == null)
        return null;

    return entity._id;
}
```

This didn't work for me. Why?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `Builders.Filter.Regex`.

```
public async Task<Entity> GetEntityIdByOriginalEmail(string originalEmail)
{
    var collection = GetCollection();
    var filter = Builders<Entity>.Filter.Regex("x", new BsonRegularExpression(originalEmail, "i"));
    return await collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Comment: But what about the ignore case sensitive i asked for

Comment: Sorry. I updated. BsonRegularExpression has second argument - options.

Comment: How to filter all fields and not just "x" for example ?

Comment: But it doesn't do exact match. It do start's with. For example if the email is liron@gmail.com and you passed liron@gmail.co as originalEmail, then also it matches.

Comment: To make it exact match you have to  write "^" + originalEmail + "$" like this.