# BsonSerializer and regular express

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a problem with parsing mongo query from string when the query contains regex filter.

the filter definition is created by

```
var bson = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(query);
var definition = new BsonDocumentFilterDefinition<CellDo>(bson);
```

The query looks like this:

```
{
   "description": {
      "$regex": /\w*\.a\b/
   }
}
```

But when the query is passed serializer throws an exception saying `JSON reader expected a string but found '/\\w*\\.a\\b/'.`

I tried to wrap regular expression in strings - the expression is treated as string so doesn't really help and I have also wrapped the expression into RegEx call, but it just thrown exception `JSON reader expected a string but found 'RegExp'.`

The queries looks like this:

```
{
    "description": {
        "$regex": "/\w*\.a\b/"
    }
}
```

```
{
    "description": {
        "$regex": RegExp(/\w*\.a\b/, "")
    }
}
```

We are currently using mongo from docker image `mongo:4.2.6-bionic` and `MongoDB.Driver 2.10.3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter with regex MongoDB C# driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184764/filter-with-regex-mongodb-c-sharp-driver)

Comment: @Munzer Not really, it is actually string input so I cannot manually create definition filter like that.

Comment: @moozywu have you resolved? Same problem here.

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira Hey I have posted answer down :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query string needs to look like the following

```
var query = @"{
   ""description"": {
      ""$regex"": ""/\\w*\\.a\\b/""
   }
};";
```

note that the regex is wrapped in quotes and you also need to escape the "\" in the string for the regex.

You can check this with the following code

```cs
var bson = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(query);

var regex = bson["description"].AsRegex;
Console.WriteLine($"regex: {regex}"); // regex: /\w*\.a\b/
```

Comment: Hey, I cannot use this approach, input to one of our endpoints is just raw mongo query.

Comment: The problem is that The deserializer is expecting `$regex` to denote that the field is a string regex, not an actual regex.

Answer (score 0):

So I figurred it out here is the solution:

You need to take your query as string. There is no way that System.Text.Json or Newtosoft.Json could parse this into some nice object.

Then your query have to use following syntax

```
{
    "description": /\w*\.a\b/
}
```

There are actually three ways to write down this query. But in dotnet driver only this one works. (Those other two are in the question)

Then you need to parse your query into BsonDocument or BsonArray when you are working with pipeline like this

```
var bson = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(query);
var bsonPipeline = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(pipeline);
```