# Mongo C# filter on integer contains

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've a collection with orders, each with an OrderId field of type `int32`. I would like to filter the collecting and get all orders where the OrderId *contains* e.g. *123*. For instance the following OrderIds must match:

- 123
- 9912399
- 99123

The following raw mongo filter works:
`{ $where: "/^.*123.*/.test(this.OrderId)" }`

How can this be expressed in the C# Mongo client or something different that does the job?

I'm not able to use the below code, as it seems to only work in string fields:

```
Builders<Order>.Filter.Regex(x => x.OrderId, new BsonRegularExpression("123"))
```

Comment: did you try `Builders<Order>.Filter.Regex(x => x.OrderId, new BsonRegularExpression("/^.*123.*/"))`?

Comment: Yes, that becomes `{ "OrderId" : /^.*123*/ }` which does not work for `int32` fields. If I change the field type to `string` that filter does work, but not for `int32`.

Comment: Try parse the raw string: `var filter = BsonDocument.Parse(@"{ $where: ""/^.*123.*/.test(this.OrderId)"" }");`

Comment: At some point. you will need to compare it at a string level.  123 in the middle of a number is technically not a numeric value.  You could use the aggregation pipeline to create a two stage aggregation - the first stage would be to convert the number to a string, the second stage to perform a regex() on the string value.

Comment: May be this will help `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184764/filter-with-regex-mongodb-c-sharp-driver?noredirect=1&lq=1`

Answer (score 2):

ideally you should store a string version of the order id in your documents. in case that's not an option you can do the following aggregation pipeline:

```cs
var res = await collection
    .Aggregate()
    .AppendStage<object>("{ $set : { orderIdString : { $toString : '$OrderId' } } }")
    .Match(Builders<object>.Filter.Regex("orderIdString", "/123/"))
    .AppendStage<object>("{ $unset : 'orderIdString' }")
    .As<Order>()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can generate `$where` via typed builders. So, as it was mentioned above, the only option you have is to create a filter from a raw MQL like below:

```
    var coll = db.GetCollection<Order>("coll");
    var result = coll.Find("{ $where: '/^.*123.*/.test(this.OrderId)' }").ToList();
```

Comment: I currently have a list of different filters dynamically using a list like `new List<FilterDefinition<Order>>()`. How can I build a FilterDefinition from a raw MQL?

Comment: do you mean different filters instead `'/^.*123.*/` constant?

Comment: if so, you can define any complex logic via $where or $function https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using:

```
x => x.OrderId.ToString()
```

instead of

```
x => x.Orderid
```

Comment: No, that does not work. `Unable to determine the serialization information for x => x.OrderId.ToString()`

Comment: May I need to try the Mongodb, but: x.OrderId.Value.Tostring() ? (I just excited.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Filter.Regex to achieve the desired behavior:

```
var valueToFilterBy = "123"
var filter = Builders<Order>.Filter.Regex(nameof(Order.Id), new BsonRegularExpression($".*{valueToFilterBy}.*"));
var data = await collection.FindAsync(filter).ToListAsync();
```